# Time Validation in p:calendar (timeOnly)

Tags: validation, date, jsf, primefaces, time

Trying to use Primefaces calendar Timeonly (TimePicker) and validating 2 timepickers in a p:datatable

Specifically,
From Time &  To Time 
Validation - To Time should not be less than From Time

In a next row of the table, a new To Time field should not be greater than the previous To Time Field ( Keeping in mind this is all for the same Date)

Is there any way to implement this ? from what I'm aware of it exists for Date, but not Time.

Thanks

Comment: Case 1
From Time (5:00 am)   To Time (8:00 am)
(Here,validation should occur such that To Time should be greater than From Time, as entered).

Case 2
<For same Date} --> Row 1 - From Time 1 (5:00 am)   To Time 1 (8:00 am), Row 2 - From Time  2 (7:00 am)  To Time 2 (2:00 pm) ... Here, Validation should happen like Case 1 as well as validation between To Time 1 and From Time 2 where From Time 2 cannot be earlier than To Time 1. 
Thanks BalusC !

Comment: Your question is hard to understand without a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve